# How do I get the network view to work in GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I've run the suggested commands [found here](https://github.com/account) but I still can't seem to get the network view working. Here's what the page/view says instead:

> If this is a Github repository you can
>   set your credentials to view your
>   network
>               git config github.user  REPO_USER
>               git config github.repo REPO_NAME

Comment: This question was edited to refer to GitHub but it was actually about [GitNub](https://github.com/Caged/gitnub).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git config github.user thrashr888@example.com  
git config github.repo the_actual_repo_name_at_github
```

Seemed to work for me this time.

Also, editing the `.git/config` file gives more insight into what things are set to. It's easy to see when things are set incorrectly.

Comment: The global settings end up in ~/.gitconfig